web scraping using beautifulSoup for google search
The following code:
import requests
import sys
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
}

res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q='+''.join(sys.argv[1:]),
                    headers=headers,
                    cookies={'CONSENT':'YES+'})
res.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
link_elems = soup.select('.r a')
num_to_open = min(5, len(link_elems))

for i in range(num_to_open):
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + link_elems[i].get('href'))

doesn't open any page. The link_elems is an empty list.
This is an exercise from the book (https://nostarch.com/automatestuff2/) "Automate the boring stuff".
I am not sure on how to use the BeautifulSoup yet. The example given in the book was a lot easier than this exercise. Just replicating the code doesn't work - which is ok, but there is a lot of additional details probably and I added the line soup.select('.r a') instead of soup.select('.package-snippet') contained in the original code, but it doesn't work.
Where is the problem?
